# Custom Dialog will not open

Tags: android, onclick, android-xml

I have a custom dialog that should launch when the android star rater widget is pressed but nothing is opening up.

XML for star rater:

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/beerRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        android:rating="0"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="rateDialog"
        />
```

The launch dialog method is:

```
public void rateDialog(View v){
        // custom dialog
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rate_stars);
        dialog.setTitle("Rate this Beer");

    }
```

Again, on clicking the small ratebar to open the dialog no dialog opens.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `dialog.show()`

```
public void rateDialog(View v){
    // custom dialog
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rate_stars);
    dialog.setTitle("Rate this Beer");
    dialog.show()         // <-- this guy here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are missing a call to

```
dialog.show();
```

However the advised way to do custom dialogs is with a [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).